# Algebra. Modeling with one-variable equations and inequalities

Tags: inequality

I'm solving problems on Khan Academy.I want to know why here 30(1-r) instead of just 30r. Please see the picture below. Thanks [image]

Comment: When you start with $30$ and take $30r$ away, you get $30-30r=30(1-r)$, basic arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

$30r$ would denote the amount the wolf demands from the pig and $30(1-r)$ would be the amount left for the pig. Notice that the expansion of the expression is $30-30r$.

Comment: It is great.Thanks. Now it is clear!!!

Answer (score 0):

The 30(1-r) is what you have left, after the 30r is taken from you, as r is a value between 0 and 1.